# How to reference column of DAX variable?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a DAX variable that contains a table. How can I reference a particular column in that variable?

For example, in the below command, the `EVALUATE` returns an error. But it works if I replace `table1` with `FactInternetSales` (which is the name of the table which contains that column)

```
define var table1=FactResellerSales
EVALUATE ROW("a",COUNTBLANK(table1[SalesAmount]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference them only using functions that iterate.
For example,

```
DEFINE
VAR _TABLE1 = FactResellerSales
EVALUATE
{COUNTX(_TABLE1 , _TABLE1 [SalesAmount)}
```

Other example of iterator functions are [sumx](https://dax.guide/sumx), [filter](https://dax.guide/filter/).